# How do I manage multiple growing lists?

Tags: c#, .net, list, min

The program starts by gathering the amount of allied/enemy minions in the game.

```
 var eminions = MinionManager.GetMinions(Player.ServerPosition, 1500 MinionTypes.All, MinionTeam.Enemy).ToList();
 var aminions = MinionManager.GetMinions(Player.ServerPosition, 1500, MinionTypes.All, MinionTeam.Ally).ToList();
```

Then i use a function that translates each object found in the lists into distances:

```
 emd.Add(eminions[0].ServerPosition.Distance(aminions[i].ServerPosition)); //the count is 5
```

Our list 'emd' contains (aminions.Count) of distances which in our example = 5.

emd[0] = 500
emd[1] = 400
emd[2] = 300
emd[3] = 200
emd[5] = 100

Here's where it get's tricky, we want to find out where the smallest distance is located in the list.  If we theorize we can see it's emd[5] = 100.  But how do i get '5'?

Summary: The program must find the smallest number in the list, and then get the position in the list where it found it.

Here's what i tried:  I tried comparing each number to see what's the smallest, if true, add to a new list, the problem im facing is that im creating too many lists and i am not prepared to handle varied amounts of minions.

```
var eminions = MinionManager.GetMinions(Player.ServerPosition, 1500, MinionTypes.All, MinionTeam.Enemy).ToList();
var aminions = MinionManager.GetMinions(Player.ServerPosition, 1500, MinionTypes.All, MinionTeam.Ally).ToList();
if (eminions.Count > 0 && aminions.Count > 0)
{
    List<double> emd = new List<double>();
    List<bool> bdistance = new List<bool>();
    for (int i = 0; i < aminions.Count; i++)
    {
        emd.Add(eminions[0].ServerPosition.Distance(aminions[i].ServerPosition));

        for (int j = 0; j < aminions.Count; j++)
        {
            if (emd[i] > emd[j])
            {
                bdistance.Add(true);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: The title is very inappropriate. You're looking for the index of the minimum. How is that managing multiple growing lists? Besides that - I support cramopy's answer as the best one - a simple loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it easily!

```
var minIndex = emd.IndexOf(emd.Min());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int pos = 0; // set index to zero
int min = emd[0]; // set minimum to first value
for (int i = 1; i < emd.Count; i ++)
{
    var val = emd[i]; // get value from position
    if (val < min) //check if value is smaller then current minimum
    {
        // set minimum to value
        min = val;
        // set minimum pos to current value pos
        pos = i;
    }
}
//found minimum
//minimum index == pos
```

Comment: Hello thank you so much for contributing i really appreciate it, i think this can work but can u add comments please? i want to know the mindset of this answer step-by-step, and thanks!!

Comment: The final `if` is unneeded - it will never be hit. The index is what we call `-1` (aka not found) only if `emd` is empty, in which case an exception will be thrown in the beginning (which I think is appropriate). Remove the last `if` and this is the best answer. Loop is better than Linq!

Comment: @adan-ramirez added comments for you

Comment: @SimpleVar removed the if statement, had forgotten to remove it after changing the logic... Thanks mate!!

Comment: Yep, I'd go for this (written as a separate method).

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
int indexMin
    = !emd.Any() ? -1 :
    emd.Select( (value, index) => new { Value = value, Index = index } )
    .Aggregate( (a, b) => (a.Value < b.Value) ? a : b )
    .Index;
```

1.The !emd.Any() ? -1 : will force a -1 if the list is empty;

2.The Select will project each int element into an anonymous type with two properties: Value and Index;

3.The Aggregate will get the element with the minimum Value;

4.Finally, we get the Index of the chosen element.

Comment: Hello thank you so much for contributing i really appreciate it, i think this can work but can u add comments please? i want to know the mindset of this answer step-by-step, and thanks!!

Comment: This is an example of the kind of code where I go "Hmm, Linq or normal code?" ... "Meh. Normal code for this one, methinks."

Comment: @Fernando 'first method will work approx 1000 times faster then second' what does that mean? explain

Comment: @adanRamirez Second method first gets minimum value spending n iteration (check all array), after it finds index of this element, also running throw all array. In case of cramopies solution, it takes n iteration, because it make only one run throw array.

Comment: @adanRamirez Sorry, two times faster :)